# pygame draw subsequent rect/color

Tags: python, pygame

Although I can draw a subsequent rect (rect with past position), I can not draw rect with subsequent color.
bodycolor has all the past color tuples. I'm on pygame 2.5 and python 3.11.4

this is bodycolor after couple of frames past

```
[]
[(32, 0, 0)]
[(64, 0, 0), (32, 0, 0)]
[(96, 0, 0), (64, 0, 0), (32, 0, 0)]
[(128, 0, 0), (96, 0, 0), (64, 0, 0), (32, 0, 0)]
[(160, 0, 0), (128, 0, 0), (96, 0, 0), (64, 0, 0), (32, 0, 0)]
```

body has similar data
so I guess that each subsequent color of subsequent rect should have different red
why is it not?

[image: my output]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = (512,512)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
sx,sy = size
cursor = (-64,0, 32,32)
dx = 0
dy = 0
body = []
color = (0,0,0)
bodycolor = []

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    bodycolor.insert(0, color)
    bodycolor.pop()
    body.insert(0, cursor)
    body.pop()
    ##print(bodycolor)
    

    dy += 32
    cursor = (dx, dy, 32,32)
    color = (dy%255,dx%255,0)

    screen.fill('black')
        
    cursorr = pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', cursor, 1)
    for c in bodycolor:
        for b in body:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, c, b)
        
    if cursorr.bottom >= sy:
        dy = -32
        dx += 32
        

    bodycolor.append(color)
    body.append(cursor)
    

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(32)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a nested loop. You go through each color and draw each rectangle for each color. At the end you see all the rectangles drawn with the last color in the list.
Instead of a nested loop, you have to use one loop, where you run through tuples of rectangles and color:

```py
for b, c in zip(body, bodycolor):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, c, b)
```